# Loading MPMovieControl for ICarousel Not Working Correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, icarousel

I am trying to achieve a iCarousel of Video URLS to allow users to see others posts.
Now i have to say i love iCarousel and this has been my only issue with it.

I have the right number of carousel objects showing up and the play button is on all of them though i'm only receiving one video at a time and the controls are not playing the video properly.

I have an NSMutableArray in place holding the `_videoURLS`, this is where i provide the number of carousel objects that need to be via `[_videoURLS count];`

In my .m file this is how i am preparing the video player with the carousel object

```
 - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view

 {

 if (view == nil)

  {   

    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 370.0f)];

    view = mainView;

    CGFloat mainViewWidth = mainView.bounds.size.width;



    //Video Player View

    _videoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainViewWidth, 220)];

    _videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:123/255.0 blue:123/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    _videoView.center = CGPointMake(100, 170);

    _videoView.tag = 7;

    [view addSubview:_videoView];



    //video

    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [_player.view setFrame:_videoView.bounds];

    [_player prepareToPlay];

    [_player setShouldAutoplay:NO];

    _player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    _player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [_videoView addSubview:_player.view]; 



    //Play Button

    _playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 60.0f)];

    [_playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play-icon-grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [_playButton addTarget:self.view.superview action:@selector(postThread:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    _playButton.center = CGPointMake(100, 160);

    _playButton.tag = 3;

    [view addSubview:_playButton];      

}

else

{

    //get a reference to the label in the recycled view

    _playButton = (UIButton *) [view viewWithTag:3];

    _videoView = (UIView *) [view viewWithTag:7];

}

//Setting Video For Each Carousel

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

    [_player setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:index]]];

    NSLog(@"Object Link: %@",[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:index]);

}    

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_player];

return view;

}
```

It works very well if i have one object in the carousel and can handle just one video, i have to be able to handle 10 videos on the carousel and if possible have them load when its focused.

From Personal experience i feel it would be the way each item is being drawn to the screen, i just cant get my finger on the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I could really use some help on this, i can even skype and try and get through it together....I need this by tomorrow! Any help!!

Comment: You can set the buttons tag as the index of carousel viewtag then from that index when u click on the button you play that index's object for play.

Comment: @JitenParmar I just tried that and i get the same result

Comment: you can give _playbutton.tag=index then - (void)btnPlay:(UIButton *)sender then also you have to give index to _player then get the _player control when u click the button then play it

Comment: @JitenParmar i believe i know what your saying, please help me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58592/icarousel-not-working-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Per the apple documentation I found out this is not capable of being done, I have chose to use the AVFoundation Framework**